# Issue in AngularJS ng-repeat while accessing image

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm writing a small program for "add to cart" page using AngularJS, the part of HTML code is as follows:

```
<div id="bookListWrapper" ng-controller="BookListCtrl">
            <form role="form">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search here...">
                </div>
            </form>
            <div>
                <ul class="list-unstyled">
                    <li class="book" style="background: white no-repeat" ng-repeat="book in books">
                        <div class="cover-image">
                            <img src={{book.imgUrl}}>
                            <!--I've tried src="../img/{{book.imgUrl}}" also-->
                        </div>
                        <div class="book-details clearfix">
                            <h3>{{book.name}}</h3>
                            <p>{{book.price}}</p>
                            <ul class="list-unstyled list-inline">
                                <li>rating: {{book.rating}}</li>
                                <li>Binding: {{book.binding}}</li>
                                <li>Publisher: {{book.publisher}}</li>
                                <li>Released: {{book.releaseDate}}</li>
                            </ul>
                            <p>Frodo, the young hobbit is playing around the neighborhood...</p>
                            <button class="btn btn-info pull-right" ng-click="addToKart(book)">Add to Kart</button>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```

The JS file is as follows:

```
var BookListCtrl = function ($scope) {
    $scope.books = [
        {
            imgUrl: "../img/lotr1.jpg",
            name: "Lord of The Rings I",
            price: 786,
            rating: 4.5,
            binding: "paperback",
            publisher: "NYpublisher",
            releaseDate: "19th July 1956",
            details: "Story of a young hobbit named Frodo, A tale of his adventures"
        },
        {
            imgUrl: "../img/lotr2.jpg",
            name: "Lord of The Rings II",
            price: 786,
            rating: 4.4,
            binding: "paperback",
            publisher: "NYpublisher",
            releaseDate: "19th July 1956",
            details: "Story of a young hobbit named Frodo, A tale of his adventures"
        },
        {
            imgUrl: "../img/lotr3.jpg",
            name: "Lord of The Rings III",
            price: 786,
            rating: 4.6,
            binding: "paperback",
            publisher: "NYpublisher",
            releaseDate: "19th July 1956",
            details: "Story of a young hobbit named Frodo, A tale of his adventures"
        }
    ];
    $scope.addToKart = function (book) {
        console.log("add to kart:body");
    }
}
```

**Although the code works just fine and shows all the images for all the items of array**, But there's a console error which says:

```
GET file:///C:/Courses/Udemy/AngularJS/html/%7B%7Bbook.imgUrl%7D%7D net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

The code directory is in the folder given in error(/C:/Courses/Udemy/AngularJS/html) whereas from JS file, it should Actually search for image in the "C:/Courses/Udemy/AngularJS/img" folder

Comment: use `ng-src` instead. Also, your `src=` doesn't have quotes

Comment: @devqon Thanks!! It works with "ng-src"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `ng-src` and here is simple cart easy to use and config . May be it will good for you .http://ngcart.snapjay.com/docs . hope it help